# autoreconf fails - libtoolize

Tags: macos, terminal

Running on mountain lion, I cannot get autoreconf to successfully run.

|ruby-1.9.3-p194| Tylers-MacBook-Pro in ~/Desktop/code/telepathic-critterdrug
○ → autoreconf -fi

Can't exec "libtoolize": No such file or directory at /sw/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 345,  line 4.
autoreconf: failed to run libtoolize: No such file or directory
autoreconf: libtoolize is needed because this package uses Libtool

Comment: sudo apt install libtool